# Javascript GPA calculator, Calculate button not working

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am new to JavaScript and html. I was trying to make a GPA calculator using Javascript and add it to my blog : http://comptechniqz.blogspot.in/2016/04/gpa-both-sems.html
The layout using html is working exactly fine but the Calculate button does nothing when it is clicked. Can you please help me in finding what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

My codes :

```
<form name="sem1">
      <table border=5 bgcolor=#BADA55 cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
                      <th>Subject</th>
                      <th>Grade</th>
             <tr>
                      <td>
                          <select name="subCRsem1_1" >
                                  <option value="3.5">UMA003</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UCB008</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEC001</option>
                                  <option value="2.5">UES009</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA007</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UEN002</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UPH004</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEE001</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UHU004</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA008</option>
                          </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type=text size=5 name="gr1" align=top maxlength=5></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                      <td>
                          <select name="subCRsem1_2" >
                                  <option value="3.5">UMA003</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UCB008</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEC001</option>
                                  <option value="2.5">UES009</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA007</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UEN002</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UPH004</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEE001</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UHU004</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA008</option>
                          </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type=text size=5 name="gr2" align=top maxlength=5></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                      <td>
                          <select name="subCRsem1_3" >
                                  <option value="3.5">UMA003</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UCB008</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEC001</option>
                                  <option value="2.5">UES009</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA007</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UEN002</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UPH004</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEE001</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UHU004</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA008</option>
                          </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type=text size=5 name="gr3" align=top maxlength=5></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                      <td>
                          <select name="subCRsem1_4" >
                                  <option value="3.5">UMA003</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UCB008</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEC001</option>
                                  <option value="2.5">UES009</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA007</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UEN002</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UPH004</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEE001</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UHU004</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA008</option>
                          </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type=text size=5 name="gr4" align=top maxlength=5></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                      <td>
                          <select name="subCRsem1_5" >
                                  <option value="3.5">UMA003</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UCB008</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEC001</option>
                                  <option value="2.5">UES009</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA007</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UEN002</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UPH004</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEE001</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UHU004</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA008</option>
                          </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type=text size=5 name="gr5" align=top maxlength=5></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                      <td>
                          <select name="subCRsem1_6" >
                                  <option value="3.5">UMA003</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UCB008</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEC001</option>
                                  <option value="2.5">UES009</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA007</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UEN002</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UPH004</option>
                                  <option value="4.5">UEE001</option>
                                  <option value="3.0">UHU004</option>
                                  <option value="4.0">UTA008</option>
                          </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type=text size=5 name="gr6" align=top maxlength=5></td>
             </tr>
             <tr align=center>
                      <td colspan=3><input type="button" value="Calculate" name="CalcButton" onclick="gpaCalc()"></td>
             </tr>
      </table>
</form>

<br>

</center>

<br>


<script language="JavaScript">

<!-- 
function gpaCalc()
{
  //define valid grades and their values
  var grade = new array(11); 
  var credit = new array(11);
  var gradeReceived = new array(6);
  var creditHour = new array(6);

  // define valid grades and their values
  grade = ['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B', 'B-', 'C', 'C-', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'X'];
  credit = [10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0];


  // retrieve user input
  gradeReceived[0] = document.sem1.gr1.value;
  gradeReceived[1] = document.sem1.gr2.value;
  gradeReceived[2] = document.sem1.gr3.value;
  gradeReceived[3] = document.sem1.gr4.value;
  gradeReceived[4] = document.sem1.gr5.value;
  gradeReceived[5] = document.sem1.gr6.value;

  // Allocate credits per subject
  creditHour[0] = document.sem1.subCRsem1_1[document.sem1.subCRsem1_1.selectedIndex].value;
  creditHour[1] = document.sem1.subCRsem1_2[document.sem1.subCRsem1_2.selectedIndex].value;
  creditHour[2] = document.sem1.subCRsem1_3[document.sem1.subCRsem1_3.selectedIndex].value;
  creditHour[3] = document.sem1.subCRsem1_4[document.sem1.subCRsem1_4.selectedIndex].value;
  creditHour[4] = document.sem1.subCRsem1_5[document.sem1.subCRsem1_5.selectedIndex].value;
  creditHour[5] = document.sem1.subCRsem1_6[document.sem1.subCRsem1_6.selectedIndex].value;

  // calculate gpa
  var totalGP = 0, GPA, totalHour=0;
  var i, j, validGrade=0;

  for(i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
           for(j=0; j<11;j++)
           {
                    if(gradeReceived[i]==grade[j])
                    {
                     validGrade=1;
                     break;
                    }
           }
           if(validGrade==1)
           {
                            totalGP+=credit[j]*creditHour[i];
                            totalHour+=creditHour[i];
           }
           else
           {
                      alert("Error-  Please use A+, A, A-, B, B-, C, C-, E, F, I or X in grades " );
                      return 0;
           }

  }
  GPA=totalGP/totalHour;
  alert("gpa =  " + eval(GPA));
  return 0;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caps your Array.

```
function gpaCalc()
{
 //define valid grades and their values
  var grade = new array(11); <-------- array has Caps in the A. should be Array(11) for all;
  var credit = new array(11);
  var gradeReceived = new array(6);
  var creditHour = new array(6);
```

[UPDATE]

Change this part of your javascript

```
if(validGrade==1)
       {
                        totalGP+=credit[j]*creditHour[i];
                        totalHour+=creditHour[i];
       }
```

to this:

```
if(validGrade==1)
       {
                        totalGP+=credit[j]*creditHour[i];
                        totalHour+=parseFloat(creditHour[i]);
       }
```

Comment: one hint here.. when you have no idea of what's happening, open the developer tools of the browser you're using and check the tab of console.. it will probably show you the error.

Comment: oh man thanks for notifying this. Now the calculate button is working but not properly :( 

Whatever inputs I am giving, the output is " gpa = NaN "
Could you help me in solving this too?

Comment: can you give me a use case of how to test that? the values I should put to see that "working"?

Comment: I am using google chrome. I pressed ctrl+shift+j to open the console. But how do we find an error using it? I copy pasted the same code as I posted here (with array instead of Array) but it didn't show me any syntax error

Comment: I added an update to the answer. If that fix your problem, check as answer so it can help others with similar problems.

Comment: Select one different subjects in each selection menu and in the corresponding text field enter a grade from A+, A, A-, B, B-, C, C-, E, F, I, X

Comment: check the answer again.. it will fix for sure. otherwise you'll have a problem with the average.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. Now I was thinking if it is possible to remove the options that have already been selected in the previous menus?